# is there only one ESP lives in the hard drive?

Tags: firmware, boot-partition

I am reading an article about the OS boot process and I read that the firmware consults the GPT to find the ESP then execute the boot loader, my question is, should each partition has its own ESP? if not, what does /boot/efi is using for?and there is any differences between ESP and /boot/efi because is mounted with the name "EFI system"

Comment: ESP *is* a partition - EFI System Partition -, only one per system required and in any case only one per drive.

Comment: Each drive can have it's own ESP; but only one will get used by your system unless your firmware reads & uses them all. Most firmware is limited to using only a single drive's ESP partition; ie. it's your box that dictates the actual rule for your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The ESP is a partition.  It would be silly if every partition had a partition.
- ESP stands for EFI System Partition
- You can *create* multiple ESP partitions, but most boot loaders will only update one of them, and most firmwares will only detect one of them for booting.  (And if they aren't the same one, you might be disappointed.)
- In linux, the ESP is typically mounted as `/boot/efi` but technically it only needs to be mounted when updating the bootloader.  Windows hides the ESP and by default does not mount it normally.
- All operating systems installed on a computer should share the same ESP.